# Error when trying to fetch data from mongodb: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm checking to see if the JOB (via the JOBID) already exists in the database and if yes, show it in the view page.

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB to HTML view page via Nodejs, Express Router and Controller. I guess the problem is with router page. I am not sure how to pass data from node to router and from router to controller. I have JOBID I need to fetch all the detail corresponding to that job ID and show it in a view page. Can you please help me?

**Router code:**

```
router.post('/RequirementView',function(req,res)
{
    addRequirement.requirementView(req,res);
    res.send(res.requirement);
});
```

**NodeJS code:**

```
exports.requirementView = function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.JobID) {
      RequirementModel.findOne({ 'JobID': req.body.JobID }, function(err, requirement) {
            if (requirement != null) {
              requirement.Vertical = req.body.Vertical || requirement.Vertical;
              requirement.save(function(err) {
                res.status(200).send(requirement);
              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing res.send() twice. Try removing res.send(res.requirement); because you already sent a response in requirementView module

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with Mongo.

The problem is caused by calling `res.send()` twice - once in `exports.requirementView` and then the second one in the `/RequirementView` handler.

It's called twice because in your route handler first you call:

```
addRequirement.requirementView(req,res);
```

(which includes `es.status(200).send(requirement);`)

and then:

```
res.send(res.requirement);
```

which is the second call to `res.send()` here.

Comment: How to fix this My Controller is main.controller('requirementDetailedViewController', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location) {

    $scope.DetailedViewRequirement = function() {


        $http.post('requirement/RequirementView',$rootScope.item).success(function(data){

            if(data){

                $location.path('RequirementDetailedView');
            }
            else{
                $scope.error_message = data.message;
                $rootScope.sess = null;
            }
        });
    }

Comment: My Controller is always empty